# How to filter today's date from ListView

Tags: django, django-views

I have models called Statistics. From views, I made a ListView to display it on the template. Now my problem is I would like to see only `today's == date_expiry`. How can I do this using `ListView`?

**models.py**

```
class Statistics(models.Model):
    site = models.CharField(max_length=264)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=264, blank=True)
    mac_add = models.CharField(max_length=264)
    minutes_used = models.CharField(max_length=265)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, blank=True)
    date_expiry = models.DateTimeField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

**views.py**

```
class DisplayStats(ListView):
    model = Statistics

    ordering = ['date']
```

**html**

```
<table class="table">
     <tr>
         <th>Site</th>
         <th>Name</th>
         <th>Mac ID</th>
         <th>Hours</th>
         <th>Date</th>
         <th>Date Expired</th>
     </tr>
     {% for clients in object_list %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{ clients.site }}</td>
            <td>{{ clients.name }}</td>
            <td>{{ clients.mac_add }}</td>
            <td>{{ clients.minutes_used|cut:".0" }}</td>
            <td>{{ clients.date }}</td>
            <td>{{ clients.date_expiry }}</td>
        </tr>
     {% endfor %}
</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can just filter it.

```
import datetime

class DisplayStats(ListView):
    model = Statistics

    ordering = ['date']

    def get_queryset(self):
        # python3
        queryset  = super().get_queryset()
        # if python2
        # queryset = super(DisplayStats, self).get_queryset()
        queryset.filter(date_expiry=datetime.date.today())
        return queryset
```

Comment: queryset.filter(date_expiry=datetime.date.today())
NameError: name 'queryset' is not defined got this error

Comment: Is it possible to filter by month?

Answer (score 2):

You can just filter the query set. You can do it two ways:

1. Override the `queryset`

   ```
   import datetime

   class DisplayStats(ListView):

       model = Statistics
       queryset = Statistics.objects.filter(date_expiry=datetime.date.today())
           ordering = ['date']
   ```
2. Use `get_queryset()`

   ```
   import datetime

   class DisplayStats(ListView):

       model = Statistics
       ordering = ['date']

       def get_queryset(self):
           return Statistics.objects.filter(date_expiry=datetime.date.today())
   ```

Comment: Is it possible to filter by month?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: How to filter the list by the most recent date on the list?